# What is the Use of this : df.columns=['count']?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Can someone please explain me the piece of code below.

```
miss = miss.to_frame()
miss.columns = ['count']
miss.index.names = ['Name']
miss['Name'] = miss.index
```

Comment: I am new to python. Just following the tutorial: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/machine-learning/machine-learning-projects/python-project/tutorial/

Comment: Assuming that you're using a Jupyter notebook to follow the tutorial, you can put these lines into the notebook to see the output and figure them out by yourself :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think code is a bit ovecomplicated, need `Series` to `2 column DataFrame` one columns from index and second from values by [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
miss = pd.Series([1,2,4], index=list('abc'))
print (miss)
a    1
b    2
c    4
dtype: int64

miss = miss.rename_axis('Name').reset_index(name='count')
print (miss)
  Name  count
0    a      1
1    b      2
2    c      4
```

Explanation of your code:

```
#convert Series to one column DataFrame
miss = miss.to_frame()
#set one column name
miss.columns = ['count']
#set index name - here not necessary
miss.index.names = ['Name']
#create column from index
miss['Name'] = miss.index
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd
    data=['aa','bb']
    miss=pd.Series(data)
    miss=miss.to_frame()
    miss.columns=['count']
    miss.index.names=['Name']
    print(miss)
    #print(a)
```

In this code to_series function convert a series object to Dataframe, DataFrame is 2D array means a form in a column and rows structure

the second line gives the name of the column which is 'count'

and the third line gives the name of the index field

output:

```
     count
Name      
0       aa
1       bb
```